# Radial Basis Function RBF Gaussian based Interpolation

Tags: approximation, interpolation, radial-basis-functions

Based on short description below (an image), how do I find the highlighted f function value? I understand that it is a value associated with the vertex, sorry I am not a good math student to understand whole RBF. Please help me.

I am doing 3d mesh deformation, basically transforming reference mesh to target mesh

============================

**Edit:**

Thanks @fang, but from programmer's point of view, i still don't understand, sorry about that. I assume the f(x) values are the corresponding output values from training data and only required when I want calculate weights(w) ? - I got the idea from articles published by Dr. James McCaffrey: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532201.aspx

Training dataset:

allData[0] = new double[] { **-0.784, 1.255, -1.332, -1.306**, *0, 0, 1* };

allData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4UAj.png) = new double[] { **-0.995, -0.109, -1.332, -1.306**, *0, 0, 1* };

allData[2] = new double[] { **-1.206, 0.436, -1.386, -1.306**, *0, 0, 1* };

*bold = input values

*italic = f(x) values?

===========================
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The $f(\mathbf{x_i})$ are the input that you want to interpolate with. In general, $\mathbf{x_i}$ is a vector of any dimension. For 2D problems where $\mathbf{x_i}=(x_i,y_i)$, you can use any bivariate function (e.g. $z=f(x,y)=3x^2+4xy+5y^2+6$) and plug in as many $(x,y)$ values to get the corresponding $z$ values. After RBF interpolation, you can then compare how well the $P_f(\mathbf{x})$ approximates the original function $f(x,y)$.